# Stripe not working when deployed to actual site

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe checkout using the test secrect key:

```
const Stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.Stripe_Secret_Key)
```

It works fine on localhost. Checkout worked fine and I can see the payment on the Stripe dashboard.

However, when I deployed it to the actual site using the same test key for testing it on the actual site and I received an error status of 502 (Bad Gateway).

I'm wondering if Stripe does not allow the test secret key to be used when deployed to the actual site?

Comment: Can you share your server side code and error logs? There're million ways that can lead to this error.

Comment: does anything in this docs help you? https://stripe.com/docs/keys

Comment: stripe involve real transaction on production. Obviously you cannot use test key.

Comment: @Yunhai no, transactions using the test key, even locally, will be displayed in the dashboard as test events.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the reason why I'm getting 502 (Bad Gateway).

I just need to do an npm install after git reset and is all working fine now. Also, I have tested it and is fine to use the Stripe test key on the production site.